# Why did I get email from UKVI RIYADH when I submitted to ABUDHABI?

Tags: visas, uk

This is what I and my husband have received today.

> Dear Customer,
>
> Your UK visa application has been issued.
>
> PLEASE DO NOT GO TO THE VISA APPLICATION CENTRE BEFORE THEY CONTACT YOU.
>
> You will be contacted by the Visa Application Centre when your documents are ready for collection, or have been dispatched via courier where this is relevant.
>
> You are reminded that you should avoid making travel plans until you have collected your passport, as the outcome of your visa application is not final until you receive your passport.
>
> Please ensure you check the details on your visa when collecting your passport.

Why is this email from RIYADH instead of ABUDHABI?
What does it mean?
How many days will it be until we get our passports back?

Comment: OP, welcome to travel.SE. Please see @KateGregory link for yor your second question. The first question you asked on which visa processing centre processes your application is interesting though, and I am not sure if there are sufficient resources here to cover that. I voted to keep it open for the time being.

Comment: Why would it matter that the email was sent from a different city? Surely it just means they processed your application somewhere else.